# Validate objects of a List using OVal

Tags: java, validation, oval

I am writing validations for a class where I specify the error message. One member is a List<> of objects of another class that also has validations. I would like to validate each object from that list so that the violations list returned by oval will have the needed information.

**Example:**

```
class A{
    @AssertValid
    List<B> items;
}

class B{
    @NotNull(message="ID can't be null")
    Integer id;
}
```

Now, let's assume that in my main I have this:

```
A obj = new A();
List<B> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add(new B());
a.setItems(items);
List<ConstraintViolation> violations = validator.validate(obj);
if(violations.size()>0) {
    System.out.println(violations.get(0).getMessage());
}
```

What it will print is "`enet.sf.oval.constraint.AssertValid: com.A is invalid`", instead of "`ID Can't be null`".

Is there an option to specify to OVal to validate each item instead of the List as a whole?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using your own MessageFormatter:

```
public class CustomMessageValueFormatter implements MessageValueFormatter {
    public static final CustomMessageValueFormatter INSTANCE = new CustomMessageValueFormatter();

    @Override
    public String format(Object value) {
        Validator validator = new Validator();
        List<ConstraintViolation> constraintViolations = validator.validate(value);
        List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        constraintViolations.forEach(v -> errorMessages.add(v.getMessage()));
        return errorMessages.isEmpty() ? value.toString() : errorMessages.toString();
    }
}

class A{
    @AssertValid(message = "{invalidValue}")
    List<B> items;
}

class B{
    @NotNull(message="ID can't be null")
    Integer id;
}
```

And before validating set your custom MessageFormatter as:

```
Validator.setMessageValueFormatter(CustomMessageValueFormatter.INSTANCE);
```

Answer (score 0):

OVal does validate the items in the list by default. The violation details are available via `ConstraintsViolatedException#getConstraintViolations()`.

The resulting `ConstraintViolation` objects have a `getCauses()` method that allows you to retrieve details about cascaded violations (i.e. violations of child objects).